# Is it possible to define a functionn as a variable?

Tags: python

working on some code has a func. that goes through if statements I want to assign this to a vaiable that i can use to redefine a list.

everything! *cries in python*

*Code here*

Expected : *Works*
Actual: *don't Works*

Comment: could you post a sample of your code? and post a more grounded expected output?

Comment: you want to use your function's name inside a piece of code?

Comment: Code? It is already hard to understand from your writing. If you are expecting some help you could as well show some effort from your side. Search around for examples.

Comment: everything is posible to do with python

Answer (score 2):

Because of the fact that functions are a type of object (a callable object) a variable can be assigned an instance of that object.

```
def bar():
    return 'foo'

x = bar

print(x) #O <function at #number>
print(x()) #Output: 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can define a function and assign that function to a variable. Then you can call that variable by providing args like any other function.

For example.

```
>>> def example_function(x, y):
...     return x + y
...
>>> func_var = example_function
>>> func_var(10, 20)                                                                                                                                          
30
```

Will work. It doesn't really accomplish anything though.

If you provide an example of what you want to accomplish I can give a better example.